# Get javascript variable value in php

Tags: javascript, php

I need to get javascript variable value in php file.

html example:
**UPDATE:**

```
$html = '
<script>
window.runParams.adminSeq="3423423423423"; 
window.runParams.companyId="2349093284234";
</script>';
```

Shout I use regex ? regex is very complex to me... any help ?

Comment: Why not pass it in GET variable ?

Comment: AJAX request or a simple redirect with a query string parameter sounds familiar?

Comment: I agree with @Rahul

Comment: I am parsing web site so I loading whole html file. I need to take value from string. UPDATED post.

Comment: any ideas how to find with regix or maybe there is more simple way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $html = '<script>
    window.runParams.adminSeq="3423423423423"; 
    window.runParams.companyId="2349093284234";
    </script>';

    $variables = ["adminSeq", "companyId"];

    $counter = 0;
    foreach($variables as $variable) {
        preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $html, $matches);
        ${"$variable"} = ($matches[1])[$counter];
        $counter++;
    }

    echo $adminSeq; // Prints out: 3423423423423
    echo $companyId; // Prints out: 2349093284234
?>
```

You can also use GET requests to do this. The link would look like `http://localhost/?adminSeq=3423423423423&companyId=2349093284234` then get out these values in PHP with:

```
<?php
$adminSeq = $_GET["adminSeq"];
$companyId = $_GET["companyId"];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Marius for reply, but I need to know that adminSeq has this code: 3423423423423. Is it possible to search for a word and get value in "". I was trying regex: [[:word:]]+\d but it gets all the numbers ...

Comment: Or to do like this: Get the line of the code where contains word "adminSeq" and get value between "". But I dont know how to write in regex ...

Comment: The code is updated and now includes variable name, added foreach loop, so you declare your variables and then foreach variable it gets the value. I hope this helped :)

Comment: Sorry but I need to get this data from string, so any variable will not help... I came up with regex: ([^\n]*adminSeq[^;]*) but I need to get digits, so in this example I am getting the code line where mets "adminSeq" till the symbol ";" but I dont know how to select only digits, do I need to write another regex ?

Comment: I fixed the code, now it creates the variable $adminSeq and gives it the value 3423423423423, then it creates the variable $companyId and gives it the value 2349093284234. That's what you wanted if I haven't misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks! and I worked arround with [^\n]*adminSeq[^\d]*(\d+)